# Recall is always 1 when using Lasso regardless of lambda value in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glmnet, precision-recall, lasso-regression

I am trying to get the prediction accuracy, precision and recall when running **Lasso logistic model** but it turns out that no matter what lambda I set, the **recall is always 1** (**even when I set lambda = 0)**

[image]

Below is my code. Here I'm using **Smartket** dataset from **ISLR** package.

```
library(ISLR)

k = 10  #10 folds cv

set.seed(42)
folds <- sample(1:k, nrow(Smarket), replace = T)

library(glmnet)

x = model.matrix(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Lag5 + Volume
, Smarket)[,-1]
y = Smarket$Direction

results <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 3))
colnames(results) <- c("Accuracy", "Precision", "Recall")

for(j in 1:k){

  lasso.mod  <-  glmnet(x[folds != j,], y[folds != j], alpha = 1,
lambda = 0.01, family = "binomial")

  preds <- predict(lasso.mod, newx = x[folds == j,], type = "response")
class <- ifelse(preds >= 0.5, "Up", "Down")

  accuracy <- sum(class == y[folds == j])/length(class)

  precision <- sum(class == "Up" & y[folds == j] == "Up")/sum(class == "Up")

  recall <- sum(class == "Up" & y[folds == j] == "Up")/sum(y[folds ==
j] == "Up")

  results[j,] <- c(accuracy, precision, recall)
}
```

Is there anything wrong in my model. I think something's wrong in my function call glmnet, not the loop because **everything's good when I use glm to call the logistic model instead of glmnet**.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a rounding issue with your results table. When I run your code I get the following:

```
    Accuracy Precision    Recall
1  0.5034965 0.4963504 0.9714286
2  0.5000000 0.4915254 0.9830508
3  0.4961240 0.4961240 1.0000000
4  0.5315315 0.5510204 0.8709677
5  0.5000000 0.4959350 1.0000000
6  0.5641026 0.5888889 0.7910448
7  0.4869565 0.4821429 0.9818182
8  0.5378151 0.5304348 0.9838710
9  0.5486726 0.5648148 0.9384615
10 0.5222930 0.5285714 0.8915663
```

I'm not sure why it is rounding just your `Recall` column. Try running the following to see if you can see the unrounded recall values:

```
print(results,digits=10)
```